# Create a New Session ID (seamless ID transfer)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, session

So I'm running into an interesting issue implementing session ID rolling after log-in/change of access levels/etc.

On log-in I'm currently trying to generate a new session ID using the SessionIDManager, however this only changes the cookie header, it doesn't swap out the session in HttpContext, so as I add additional details to the session (various details to bind the user to the session ID), they immediately get lost (not to mention the old session gets abandoned).

To prevent session hijacking (by storing primary non-SSL communication) and session fixation, we should generate a new Session ID upon log in, but Microsoft doesn't seem to allow you to do that (grr, so many read-only variables and sealed classes with no constructors). I could just migrate all data in the backend SQL, but that seems a bit "dirty hack".

Any ideas on how to properly do this?

Edit:

Implementations I've found:

```
Session.Abandon();
Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie("ASP.NET_SessionId", ""));
```

Session still is the old session, so on next page, all changes are lost.

SessionIDManager doesn't return a session object after SaveSessionID, so I cannot add details to the session I just created. On the next page load I can, but the old session is now inaccessible (and abandoned, but even if it wasn't abandoned...).

HttpContext.Session is read only, even if it wasn't, HttpSessionState doesn't have a constructor.

Edit 2:

[Session Fixation in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2402312/session-fixation-in-asp-net)

Apparently session fixation and hijacking have been talked about before here, with the answer being "Microsoft doesn't seem to care", with a poorly implemented two-phase fix.

Comment: Why would you need to change the session ID *to a specific value* and still keep the same session? If you drop any of these requirements (even just the "specific value" part) it would not present a problem.

Comment: No specific value required, it's just how SessionIDManager does it (returns the new ID).  If I have a way to get .NET to generate a new session ID, transfer everything, abandon the old one and generate the proper headers, I'm fine. I'm having problems getting .NET to generate a new session object and get everything transferred into it regardless of the handful of methods found on the net (all generate new IDs on next page load, or generate same page but don't touch HttpContext.Session).

Comment: I'm curious as to why you need to do this...

Comment: Sniff a session ID generated on non-SSL entry to the website, hijack it a few minutes later when they've likely logged in. Also prevents some session fixation attacks. It's pretty basic to implement in other languages, bleh.

Comment: Just reset the session values.  Why would you need a new session ID?  As long as the values represent the changes to the values.  I can't see why anything else is necessary.

Comment: "Just reset the session values.", ok, so a user goes to log in, and I reset all the session values. Now the user isn't logged in anymore because they have no session information.

Comment: I would do that in the backend SQL because that is in the end much better if your web application ever is hosted in a loadbalanced environment (web-server-farm)...

Comment: @Yahia, yep that seems to be the _easiest_ way, but I'd rather build it in a way that works regardless of backend (being as HttpSessionState implements the SQLServer details), and would be a bit more clean than basically swap the IDs on the table (ick), however at this rate your answer may honestly be the best one. :( Hasn't anyone implemented these security measures in .NET?! :P

Comment: see https://connect.microsoft.com/feedback/viewfeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=143361&siteid=210#details - it seems the *easiest way* is most probably the one to go in this case...

Comment: another option is to use SSL from the beginning on...

Comment: @Yahia: During the SSL redirect the session ID gets transferred in the clear.

Comment: @StrangeWill I am not talking about a redirect...

Comment: @Yahia: how do I enforce that our customers always type "https://"?

Comment: you don't... you just do the "redirect" differently... i.e. from a different ASP.NET app or even from "normal/static" http-page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, so this is a bit of an issue, showed how you can hijack session based auth AND forms based auth using this method (you'll need a valid user account, but you can hijack someone else's session), there are some blogs online that complain about session fixation and the ability to easily exploit hijacking. So obviously this is a huge issue. [Yahia](https://stackoverflow.com/users/847363/yahia) pointed out Microsoft isn't interested in [fixing this](https://connect.microsoft.com/feedback/viewfeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=143361&siteid=210#details).

What I did was create an authenticity key that got paired with the session ID, upon log in we'd generate a new one and put it in the session and give the user a cookie, if there was a key in the session they must match, if not we'd kick the user (hijacking attempt). It seems to be a common way to do this on the blogs mentioned (another is to use forms auth to basically encrypt the cookie, while this works fine I wanted the solution to be compatible with multiple types of authentication).

---

One thing that was recommended that could help is to prevent any non-ssl communication by using another application as the non-ssl front end that just serves 302 redirects, as recommended by [Yahia](https://stackoverflow.com/users/847363/yahia), while this helps a ton by preventing the disclosure of the session IDs in the first place, it would require a lot of restructuring of how the applications are deployed to fix, and IMO: .NET's iffy session management should be fixed in the first place, and I wanted our applications to be fully secured from the ground up, not dependent on other applications to do 302 redirects so that any information leakage is irrelevant being as the cookie will rotate on log in.

Answer (score 0):

Did you look at `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie` method?

Try something like this:

```
FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
HttpContext.Current.Session.Abandon();
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(newCode, true);
```

I hope this will help you....

Comment: Forms authentication is an entirely different cookie (and you'll still lose all data after you abandon it with no transfer of information). I actually showed a PoC hijacking on forms auth too due to the inability to rotate session IDs (there are some blogs that detail this). I'll drop what I did in a comment to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

My answer's a little late, but I was looking for the same things so I thought I should post what I found...  Instead of using the SessionIdManager to reset the cookie, it seemed like a better "hook" would be to install a custom session id manager:

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" ... 
              sessionIDManagerType="MyAssembly.SessionFixationIdManager, MyAssembly" />
```

Then, I implemented my ISessionIdManager using the existing SessionIdManager.  For example:

```
class SessionFixationIdManager : ISessionIDManager
{
    private SessionIDManager _originalManager = new SessionIDManager();

    public string CreateSessionID(System.Web.HttpContext context)
    {
        // Default process for creating session IDs is fine...
        return _originalManager.CreateSessionID(context);
    }

    etc.
}
```

The only method I made different was the GetSessionID method -- if the request is not authenticated, then ignore the incoming cookie and issue a new one:

```
public string GetSessionID(System.Web.HttpContext context)
{
    // Never use a session ID from an unauthenticated request...
    if (!context.Request.IsAuthenticated) 
        return null;

    return _originalManager.GetSessionID(context);
}
```

By doing this, it seems to guarantee that:

1. The Session ID cookie will be reissued on the response that authenticates the user.  I'm using Forms Authentication, so that is the response that issues the Forms Authentication Cookie.
2. I can actually **use the session on the request where I authenticate the user** - since the Session ID was reassigned **before** the session was assigned to the Context of that Request.

Now, this is only the beginning of the effort regarding security.  For example, I still need to do something to tie the session to the authenticated user (e.g. encrypt some session value into the forms authentication cookie).  And it means I can't use Session State during the login process (it must all be handled as a single request, or using ViewState, etc.).

But I think this guarantees that an unauthenticated user cannot perform session fixation.

(Honestly, I'm not sure yet if this will be worth it.  Validating the forms authentication data (or some other authenticity key) against the session on each request probably provides the same level of security without these extra hoops to jump through.  But implementing the security best-practice is a goal, and I think this will work without the screwy two-phased work-around that loses all context of the initial request...)