# Sql server session mode in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008-r2

I used sql server session mode in my application. The session id is generated as soon as the page loads. I have a user login in the start page. But I need the session id to be created after the user login is successful. 
**In web.config file**

```
<sessionState mode="SQLServer" sqlConnectionString="DBConnection" allowCustomSqlDatabase="true" regenerateExpiredSessionId="false" cookieless="false" timeout="1" ></sessionState>

<add name="DBConnection" connectionString="Data Source=localhost;DataBase=ASPState;Integrated Security=True;uid=sa;pwd=password-1" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

How the session id is created ? as the page loads. Do I need to specify any code in the user login method.

[image: Session]

Any suggestions..

**EDIT** 
When the Login page is loaded, the session id is created in ASPState database as below.

```
SessionId   Created Expires     LockDate    LockDateLocal   LockCookie  Timeout Locked  SessionItemShort    SessionItemLong Flags
sf4chi20mebkfaw4taz345h5739e38f4    2013-01-08 12:38:23.340 2013-01-08 12:39:23.340 2013-01-08 12:38:23.340 2013-01-08 18:08:23.340 1   1   0   0x010000000000FF    NULL    0
```

Can I set the session to be created after the login is completed. ?

Comment: Why do you think you need to create a new session ID? What is the problem you are trying to fix by that? Please add those details to your question.

Comment: I dont want to create new session id.when the application starts , the session id is created. But can i manually set the session id to be created after the login is successful.

Comment: We understand what you are trying to do. The question is why ? Why do you not want sessions to be created on the login page ?

Comment: This isn't how sessions work really... As Hans says, you are probably trying to fix a problem with the wrong approach or you are fixing a non-existant problem...

Comment: Can i know how the session id is created as the application starts.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can i know how the session id is created as the application starts.?

The session isn't created as the application starts but rather when the user firsts hits the application.

> Can I set the session to be created after the login is completed. ?

You need to [call `Session.Abandon()` and then clear the session ID cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2416037/128217) once the user is authenticated.

For those of you that think that the OP is trying to solve a problem that doesn't exist, please read up on [session fixation attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_fixation).