# how to change session id during login in asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-core

I need to assign a new session Id as part of the login request on asp net core 2.2, this is required to prevent session hijacking.

The session.clear method leaves the cookie intact, and I can remove the session cookie using for example

```
Response.Cookies.Delete("ASP.NET_SessionId");
```

But this prevents the login from working, old asp net used to have a session abandon but I cant see an equivalent.

Any help appreciated. Thanks

Comment: At currently , there is no obvious counterpart to the pre-ASP.NET Core Abandon method which ends the session. if Delete cookie is not acceptable in your scenario , the only way is to check whether session is empty on server side and write some logic .

Comment: Kindly check this link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1368403/generating-a-new-asp-net-session-in-the-current-httpcontext

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Session Fixation - Change sessionId on asp.net core 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47335370/session-fixation-change-sessionid-on-asp-net-core-2)